# PHP - способы объявления функции

Tags: php

В PHP всегда объявлял функции вот так:

```
function name(n1,n2,...){
    ...
}
```

сейчас в одной из библиотек нашел вот такой способ:

```
$name = function(n1,n2,...){
            ...
        }
```

Есть ли какая-то особая разница между этими способами?

Я заметил только разницу в вызовах: `name(...)` и `$name(...)`

Comment: В первом случае у вас глобально объявленная функция. Во втором переменная со ссылкой на функцию, которая может быть не видна в каких либо областях видимости и значение которой в любой момент может быть изменено и представлять собой уже другую функцию или вообще не функцию

Comment: [анонимные функции](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php) включают много различных аспектов, начиная с того, что представляются классом, и далее нюансы с захватом родительских переменных, статических вызовов, всяких удобств типа определения там где надо (а-ля определение в месте ее передачи как callback метода) и т.д. и т.п.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как ответ в комментах, и вопрос, по-факту, остался открыт, перенесу комментарии в ответ:

> В первом случае у вас глобально объявленная функция. Во втором
> переменная со ссылкой на функцию, которая может быть не видна в каких
> либо областях видимости и значение которой в любой момент может быть
> изменено и представлять собой уже другую функцию или вообще не
> функцию.
>
> @Mike
>
> [Анонимные функции](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php) включают много различных аспектов, начиная с того,
> что представляются классом, и далее нюансы с захватом родительских
> переменных, статических вызовов, всяких удобств типа определения там
> где надо (а-ля определение в месте ее передачи как callback метода) и
> т.д. и т.п.
>
> @teran